# Does anyone know what kind of caterpillar this is?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I was out hiking, and was walking along the side of a road, and saw this little guy on some gravel. Hes a light blue/grey color, hairy, spotted with red,and looks like he has horns and a tail. I've been trying to search for what species it is. If anyone knows, please share!

[image: Caterpillar]
<sup>(Click to view full image)</sup>

Comment: Nice picture! Where and when did you take the photograph?

Comment: In colorado springs, Cheynne mountain, and just a few days ago!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks similar to a Rusty Tussock Moth (*Orgyia antiqua*) caterpillar, but you might want to check [the bugguide page for the species](http://bugguide.net/node/view/28152), or submit your photo there for a second opinion.

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked the moth up and there was a youtube video of one. Thats definitely my little guy. once again, thanks!